# Aws cognito presigned url getting error as token expiration

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I developing an android mobile app in which it is used to upload the image and save in s3. When I am uploading the photo I am generating a pre-signed URL for that image and saving the URL in my database so whenever the application loads the saved URL gets called from my database and display the image.B ut in my case, the pre-signed URL gets an error stating that token expired. I need to access the image from s3 using the URL which was generated while uploading

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, pre-signed URLs have an expiry time associated with them that you can specify when you create the pre-signed URL. For the expiry time, the minimum value you can set is 1, and the maximum is 604800 (seven days). (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)

While you haven't mentioned what the expiry time is set for your pre-signed URLs, in general the approach of generating the URL, storing it in your database and using it going forward in the app is bound to fail. You should consider either computing the URL on the fly ( by storing the location details of the file) or optimize it by tracking when the URL has expired (you could have a expiry-time field in your database) and updating the URL as needed